# How do I populate an array with palindromes using a loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested

First time on this site and first java class ever.  I am stuck trying to populate an array with palindromes.  I have tried the everything with no luck.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I've coded so far.

```
public class PalindromeListArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declare variables.    
        int digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5;
        final int MAX = 10;
        int x=0;
        //Create an array of size 25.
        String[] palindromeList = new String[25];
        //Generate numbers.
        for (digit1 = 1; digit1 < MAX; digit1++)
           for (digit2 = 0; digit2 < MAX; digit2++)
              for (digit3 = 0; digit3 < MAX; digit3++)
                 for (digit4 = 0; digit4 < MAX; digit4++)
                    for (digit5 = 0; digit5 < MAX; digit5++)
                        if (digit1 == digit5 && digit2 == digit4)
                            for(x=0; x < palindromeList.length; ++x){ 
                                //Populate array with palindromes.
                                palindromeList[x] = String.valueOf(digit1) + String.valueOf(digit2) + String.valueOf(digit3) + String.valueOf(digit4) + String.valueOf(digit5);
                                System.out.println(x + "\t" + palindromeList[x]);
                            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the inner for loop?  seems like you just want `palindromeList[x] = ...; x++;` in the innermost if.

Comment: Yeah. Remove `for x=0` loop and use `palindromeList[x++] = String.valueOf(digit1`... and include a test to keep x < 25.

Comment: I'm trying to stop generating numbers once I've got 25 elements in the array. I've played around with placement of the last loop with different results, but no success.  When I do as you suggest, I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundesException.

Comment: Great!  I added an if test before palindromeList[x] = ... and it worked. I can't believe it's so simple. Thank you!!

Comment: But you did "lose" the "for x = 0..." loop, too, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along these lines:

```
...
  if(x == palindromeList.length) break;
  palindromeList[x++] = String.valueOf(digit1) + String.valueOf(digit2) + ...
}
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
   System.out.println(i + "\t" + palindromeList[i]);
...
```

You were in the ball park.